# mysql client gives no output when trying to connect to a remote DB

Tags: mysql

I am trying to connect from a Raspbian shell to a remote MySQL database (Windows).

I freshly installed mysql-client and mysql-server (version 5.5.55) and now try following command:

`mysql -v -h hostname -uroot -pmypass db_name`

I get no response at all. Program does not exit or print anything just keeps hanging.

Connecting to a local DB works fine with `mysql -uroot -pmypass`.

I am quite confused why the client does not print anything even with the verbose option being set on.

Thanks!

Comment: Check your my.cnf. make sure bind-address variable is comment and make sure 3306 port is open.

Comment: Commenting bind-address property helped, I started getting responses from the client. Thank you!

Comment: OK I'm posting my comment to help another people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `my.cnf` settings.
Make sure the `bind-address` variable is commented or its value is `0.0.0.0`

Make sure `port 3306` (MySQL Default Port) is open (Both on the server and on the client).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and most of the solutions given are:

1. Change config file to allow port/address
2. Allow program/port through firewall
3. Check the IP/URL for the remote connection

But in my case, the database was hosted on a remote server and the router required port forwarding.

1. Go to your router settings (Open browser and type in 192.168.0.1 or similar)
2. Enter credentials (mostly admin/admin or admin/password)
3. Find "forwarding" or "port forwarding" in menu
4. Create new entry (In my case I used postgres so 5432 port with TCP)

Hope it helps.